# Why can we take the following sequence of compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, metric-spaces

I'm studying the proof which goes as follows. Let $\mu$ be a tight Borel probability measure on $L^\infty(X)$, where the set $X$ is not necessary countable. Take $(K_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, an increasing sequence of compact sets in this space with $\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n)=1$.

How do I know that such sequence exists?

By definition, $\mu$ is tight if $\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists K\subset L^\infty(X)$ compact such that
$$\mu(K)>1-\varepsilon$$

How can I relate this to $(K_n)$?

Comment: Any assumptions on $X$? Any space? Or locally compact metric, e.g.?

Comment: The existence of such a sequence is precisely the definition of "tight measure".

Comment: I thought tight = inner regular?

Comment: So $\mu$ is a measure on $X$, not on $L^\infty(X)$ ?

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: $\mu$ is on $L^\infty(X)$, $X$ is a pseudo-metric space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of "tight", for every $n$, taking $\epsilon = 1/k$ there exists a compact set $E_k$ such that $\mu(E_k) > 1 - 1/k$.  Set $K_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k$, which is also compact, and we have $K_1 \subset K_2 \subset \cdots$.  Note that $E_n \subset K_n$, so $\mu(K_n) > 1-1/n$. Then $\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n) > 1-1/n$ for every $n$, so $\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n)=1$.